# Relation doesn't exist in django restframework

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am creating one crud operation in django restframework and I have created project name "portfolio" and app "stock" and store in postgres database Here is my code.

stock.models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Stocks(models.Model):
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    Number_of_Share = models.IntegerField()
    Unit_Price = models.IntegerField()
    ShareValue=models.IntegerField()
    Total_Share_Value= models.IntegerField()
```

stock.serializers.py

from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Stocks

```
class StocksSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model =Stocks
        fields = '__all__'
```

stock.viewset.py

```
from rest_framework import viewsets
from .models import Stocks
from . import serializers

class StockViewset(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Stocks.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.StocksSerializer
```

portfolio.router.py

```
from stock.viewsets import StockViewset
from rest_framework import routers

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register('Stocks',StockViewset)
```

portfolio.urls.py

```
from django.urls import path, include
from .router import router

urlpatterns = [
    # path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('portfolio/',include(router.urls))
]
```

But I am facing this error.

```
Exception Type: ProgrammingError
Exception Value:    
relation "stock_stocks" does not exist
LINE 1: ...reValue", "stock_stocks"."Total_Share_Value" FROM "stock_sto...
```

Please help me solve this error.

Comment: Did you properly made migrations and migrated the database?

Comment: ya just open database and saw its table and realized, I have migrated everything but not model. Thanks problem solve